# SQL Query select one row based on results of another row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I included a screenshot of a demo entry to the table.  I know how to write an SQL query to select data when all the information is on the same row, but this presents a new challenge to me.  I want to select the meta_value result to a meta_key for a user_id only if pw_user_status has the value of approved.  I'm not sure how to write this kind of query.

Source data:

[image]

Comment: Can you at least show us what your expected output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery which identifies users having approved status, and then select certain key/value pairs for those users:

```
SELECT meta_key, meta_value
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE t1.meta_key IN ('nickname', 'first_name', ...) AND
     EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
             WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND
                   t2.meta_key = 'pw_user_status' AND
                   t2.meta_value = 'approved')
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester